# The MOSFET driver function in high and low side

Tags: transistors, driver

Does the MOSFET gate need a high voltage in order to turn on the MOSFET as well?

What is the difference of high and low side of MOSFET? Is there any effect?

Comment: I think your question relates to the use of a N-mosfet as a high side switch (controlling the positive side of the load). If that is the case refer to [this reply](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/95260/33841) for the problems it introduces.

Answer (score 1):

High-side switching is when the load is between the drain and the supply, low-side switching is when the load is between the source and ground.